# How do I use Install4j auto-update feature?

Tags: java, install4j, auto-update

Install4j has an auto-update functionality that runs silently each time the user starts the program. I want to configure it, but even after following [this](https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/v/8.0/help/doc/concepts/autoUpdate.html) guide I can't make it work.

I placed the updates.xml [here](https://github.com/Mamiglia/Reddit-Wallpaper/tree/main/.build/Install4j) ([here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Mamiglia/Reddit-Wallpaper/main/.build/Install4j/updates.xml) the raw link) and the "media" file is in the same folder, so why doesn't it work? Is it that I can't use github for this purpose?

[image: My Installer and Updater]

Comment: How do you invoke the update downloader?

Comment: @IngoKegel I followed the strategy 2 of the guide, so I add an update scheduler to the installer and add an "update downloader with silent version check" that is intetgrated into the launcher. So from what I understood is the launcher that invokes the updater (edited the post with an image of my situation)

Comment: Maybe the window detection does not work in your case. Try changing the "Launch mode" from "When first window is shown" to "Blocking at startup". To see what the update download is doing, start it from the command line with the argument `-Dinstall4j.log=<path to writable file>`.

Comment: @IngoKegel I can't understand the log, it feels like it's saying that everything is already up-to-date? [Full Log](https://pastebin.com/jb8jjiMy), [Updater part of the log](https://pastebin.com/TEat91jt):

Comment: Did you add the "Check for update" action to the installer? This will not work, it just downloads updates.xml and sets the update descriptor to a variable. See the update downloader template and how its actions are configured to learn more about the actual mechanism.